# CSS animation while using a virtual dom and maintaining state

Tags: javascript, css, redux, virtual-dom

Using vanilla JS, Redux to manage state, and a virtual dom, how could you animate an item in a grid while maintaining state and not having the virtual dom rip out the change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an action dispatcher that'll generate and dispatch new animation properties to the redux store every `N`ms.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow. Would you mind elaborating a bit more? Thanks!